# add animated actor on stage with libgdx

Tags: java, animation, libgdx, box2d, actor

libgdx are new and would add to the Stage actor performing an animation , composed of several frames .
This is the code I found online with already applied my images of movement :

```
public class AnimatedImage extends Image
{
    private float stateTime = 0;
    TextureRegion w1 = new TextureRegion(new Texture("wave/wave1 - Copy.png"));
    TextureRegion w2 = new TextureRegion(new Texture("wave/wave2 - Copy.png"));
    TextureRegion w3 = new TextureRegion(new Texture("wave/wave3 - Copy.png"));
    TextureRegion w4 = new TextureRegion(new Texture("wave/wave4 - Copy.png")); //1088 308
    Animation animation = new Animation(1f/4f, w1, w2, w3, w4);

    public AnimatedImage(Animation animation) {
        super(animation.getKeyFrame(0));
        this.animation = animation;
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta)
    {
        ((TextureRegionDrawable)getDrawable()).setRegion(animation.getKeyFrame(stateTime+=delta, true));
        super.act(delta);
    }
}
```

Now , in the Create () method , you can declare the class and add it to the stage?
type

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
AnimatedImage anim = new AnimatedImage() ;
stage.addActor (anim) ;
```

I would treat animation as actors , thanks
it's possible ?

Comment: Why don't you test it if its possible? Or do you have any problems executing it? The only problem might be that you create 4 textures each time you create an animated image and you can never dispose them, so you get a memory leak. (And you should probably use a texture atlas). And why the box2d tag?

Comment: i have problem of executing

Comment: Then specify the problem. Did you set up a libgdx project correctly? Did you actually create the AnimatedImage class and did not paste the code in "an empty file"? Where are you calling that stuff, etc... No one knows what you do, so how should we know what your problem is? Did you get an exception? If post the stack trace and the lines of code that causes it, etc... You ask if it is possible, which it is -> question answered?